# Cannot find symbol error in Test Class

Tags: java

This is my student class.

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private long id;
    private double gpa;
    private PersonalData pd;

    public Student(String name, long id, double gpa, PersonalData pd){
        this.name= name;
        this.id=id;
        this.gpa= gpa;
        this.pd= pd;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public long getID(){
        return id;
    }

    public double getGPA(){
        return gpa;
    }

    public PersonalData getPersonalData(){
        return pd;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String result= "Name: "+ name+ ", ID: "+ id+ ", GPA: "+gpa+", Personal Data: "+ pd;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here is the test class:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO, add your application code
        PersonalData a= new PersonalData(80,4,1,1232154687);
        Student b= new Student(Ali,123,20,a);
    }
}
```

It gives this error:

```
cannot find symbol
        Student b= new Student(Ali,123,20,a);
                               ^
  symbol:   variable Ali
  location: class Test
1 error
```

I don't know what is wrong. Is there anyone can see?

Comment: Your constructor accept a `String` variable as name. So put Ali in quotes (`"Ali"`).

Comment: Thank you @ZouZou. I have been wringt code for many hours so I couldnt see properly simple things Thank you again

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cannot find symbol" error - even on a ridiculously simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777554/cannot-find-symbol-error-even-on-a-ridiculously-simple-example)

Answer (score 0):

Make it like below

```
student b= new Student("Ali",123,20,a);
```

Your `Student` class `constructor` requires `String` as name either you have to pass it as in "" or Make a String variable like `String Ali=""` then pass Ali as

```
student b= new Student(Ali,123,20,a);
```

Comment: Explanation will be very helpful for OP.