# how do i fix this scanner new scanner error?

Tags: java

I get this error when trying to use the Scanner object:

```
Main.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
```

The `Scanner` library is already imported

Here is my code :

```
Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
public int play(int pieces){
    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in); 
    int num;
    num = in.nextInt();

    return pieces-in;
}
```

Comment: OP has mentioned that it is already imported.

Comment: Is any class in your project named `Scanner` ? If **yes** use `java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't make sense. What are `pieces` and `in` ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return pieces-num`?

Comment: your return statement is not proper `return pieces-in;` `(you can't perform operation on two different data type variable , one is primitive other one is reference type)` also your code is ambiguaous

Comment: Look in your IDE for line 105, and tell us which line that is. The error is at line 105. The main problem is you're subtracting `in` which is of type `Scanner` from `pieces` which is of type `int`.

Comment: i made it :return pieces-num but it still give the error

Comment: You're also declaring and instantiating the same `Scanner` object twice. You only need to do it once.

Comment: Which is line 105 in the snippet you gave us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`in` is you Scanner object. The value you read is in the variable `num`, you must use that variable in the return statement.

```
public int play(int pieces){
    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in); 
    int num;
    num = in.nextInt();

    return pieces-num;
}
```

Comment: Look at this post, is it possible you didn't create the packages structure ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777554/cannot-find-symbol-error-even-on-a-ridiculously-simple-example

Comment: The code is good, I tested it successfully, so it must be something with how you compile or un it. You might also want to check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean

Comment: i see it could be lots of things. i will try a few things. thx. at least i know the code is good.